# Instagram Basic Display returns media url with Bad Url Timestamp message

Tags: url, timestamp, instagram, instagram-api, http-status-code-403

Integrated the **Instagram Basic display API** with my website. It was working fine. From last few days some of the media url throws error code **403** with the message **Bad Url Timestamp**(these media were working fine earlier). I have tried refreshing the access token and creating a new one but it was not of any help. Not all the media but few of them are giving this error.

The url which is giving error

https://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/128209372_3881072401959620_4985839256926707810_n.jpg?_nc_cat=108&ccb=2&_nc_sid=8ae9d6&_nc_ohc=KduPs8x3j9QAX944ddk&_nc_ht=scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com&oh=3917991f8e3aaffbcf5f3017a9d78f26&oe=6002114

Can anyone help? TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Instagram Basic display API have been updated. We need to stop using old API and switch to use new Instagram Basic display API.

Please refer these links:

https://embedsocial.com/blog/instagram-api-changes-2020/

https://www.instagram.com/developer/